# Topology question regarding circle on mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I have a flat plane and made some topology on the mesh. One one side I want to make a circle in the mesh, and I'd like to know the correct method not to leave any Ngons on the mesh. I know its a flat plane and I can get away with this, but is there also another solution where to join those vertices which are in Red to get Quad, and make the topology better?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it these ways:

[image]

[image]

But it seems unnecessarily complicated, I would simply do it with tris:

[image]